# Spree Admin: change /admin to /customadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, spree

First off, I have googled the ever-loving s*** out of this problem.  I've researched and worked on it. To date, I've not been successful.

My spree site has that familiar link.../admin

For security purposes, I'd prefer that url was inaccessible to the public.  I'd prefer that we can obfuscate that traditional admin path to something like....say...../mycustomadmin

Here's what I'm working with:Nginx, Rails 4, AWS application stacks running Ubuntu

*Possible approaches
  --can we do this at the Nginx level?

--maybe this should be handled in the routes.rb file via namespace or scope.. or even match

--what about rails 4 initializers?  is there a way to initialize success?

*HINTS and TRYS

-- I looks like the Nginx "internal;" flag would work with an Nginx rewrite. It didn't work.

-- I must consider "/admin" references from third-party gems

If you have any good ideas that work (thus solving the problem), I'll send you an effing edible arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

Your only decent option is to fork spree, and modify this line of code in spree_backend:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.2.0/backend/config/routes.rb#L4

I thought you could do some re-writes somehow, but the links generated by Spree are always going to point to admin unless that namespace is changed.

When you want to upgrade spree, you'll need to rebase your change on top of the newer version of Spree.